# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(k\pi\frac{2m+1}{n+1})}k>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(k\pi\frac{2m+3}{n+1})}k$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, summation

A few days ago I asked a question about an interesting property of the partial sums of the series $\sum\sin(nx)/n$.
Here's the link:
[Bound the absolute value of the partial sums of $\sum \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3931465/bound-the-absolute-value-of-the-partial-sums-of-sum-frac-sinnxn)

The proof given there left some details for me, in particular I have to prove that
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k}
\sin\left(k\pi\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\right) >
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1 \over k}\sin\left(k\pi\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\right)
$$
for every natural $n$ and $m$ such that $m = 0, 1, \ldots, \left\lfloor\left(n-1\right)/2\right\rfloor$. I don't think this is relatively simple; anyway I tried a few expansions with sum-to-product and viceversa formulas, but everything I tried leads to $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(2(m+1)x_k)\sin(x_k)}{k} < 0$$
where $x_k = k\pi/(n+1)$. From here I don't see any further semplification. Also I noted that $\sin(x_k)$ is always positive since $k$ is at most $n$, but we can't say much about $\cos$.
Then I tried to pair terms since for $k' = n+1-k$ we have $\sin(x_k) = \sin(x_k')$, which gives $$\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}\left[\frac{\cos(2(m+1)x_k)}{k}+\frac{\cos(2(m+1)x_{k'})}{n+1-k}\right]\sin(x_k) < 0$$ for $n$ even. Then I hoped that the term between square brackets were always negative, but it's not always the case... How can I do?

Comment: have you tried taking derivative of $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{\sin(k\pi\frac{2x+1}{n+1})}{k}$ and see if it is negative on $0\leq x\leq\frac{n-1}{2}$?

Comment: Actually yes, but then I forgot that we can sum the resulting sum, as it is a sum of $\cos(kx)$. I will try again! Thank you in the meantime!

Comment: and yeah so if you just sum that bastard and integrate again, wouldn't you get a closed formula too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already determined the local maxima of a partial sum $S_n(x)$ in $[0,\pi]$ are at
$x_{n,m} = \frac{2m+1}{n+1} \pi$ for $m = 0,1, \ldots ,\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$.

We first show that the vertical distance between successive peaks is diminishing in that

$$S_n\left(\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi \right) - S_n\left(\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi \right)>  S_n\left(\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi \right) - S_n\left(\frac{2m+5}{n+1}\pi \right) > \ldots $$

Note that $\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi = \frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi + \frac{2\pi}{n+1}$ and

$$S_n'\left(x\right) - S_n'\left(x+ \frac{2\pi}{n+1} \right) = \frac{\sin \frac{n}{2}x \cos \frac{n+1}{2}x}{\sin \frac{x}{2}} - \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n}{2}x+ \frac{n\pi}{n+1} \right) \cos \left(\frac{n+1}{2}x+\pi\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)} \\ =\frac{\sin \frac{n}{2}x \cos \frac{n+1}{2}x}{\sin \frac{x}{2}} - \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n}{2}x- \frac{\pi}{n+1} \right) \cos \frac{n+1}{2}x}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)} \\ = \frac{\cos \frac{n+1}{2}x}{\sin \frac{x}{2}\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)}\left[\sin \frac{x}{2}\sin \left(\frac{n}{2}x+ \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right) -\sin \frac{x}{2}\sin \left(\frac{n}{2}x- \frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)  \right]$$

Applying angle addition identities and  simplifying we eventually get

$$\tag{1}S_n'\left(x\right) - S_n'\left(x+ \frac{2\pi}{n+1} \right) = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{n+1}\sin (n+1)x}{\cos \frac{\pi}{n+1} - \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n+1} +x \right)}$$

Now consider the points

$$\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi \leqslant  \frac{2m+2}{n+1}\pi-\frac{y}{n+1} \leqslant \frac{2m+2}{n+1} \leqslant \frac{2m+2}{n+1}\pi+\frac{y}{n+1} \leqslant \frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi, \\ \frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi \leqslant  \frac{2m+4}{n+1}\pi-\frac{y}{n+1} \leqslant \frac{2m+4}{n+1} \leqslant \frac{2m+4}{n+1}\pi+\frac{y}{n+1} \leqslant \frac{2m+5}{n+1}\pi$$

Using (1) with $x_- = \frac{2m+2}{n+1}\pi-\frac{y}{n+1}$, $x'_-= x_- + \frac{2\pi}{n+1} = \frac{2m+4}{n+1}\pi-\frac{y}{n+1}$, $x_+ = \frac{2m+2}{n+1}\pi+\frac{y}{n+1}$,  and$x'_+=x_+ + \frac{2\pi}{n+1} =  \frac{2m+4}{n+1}\pi+\frac{y}{n+1}$we get

$$G'(y) = \frac{d}{dy} \left[S_n \left(x_-) -  S_n \left(x'_-\right) \right] - S_n(x_+) - S_n(x'_+)\right] \\ = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{n+1} \sin y}{n+1}\left[\frac{1}{\cos \frac{\pi}{n+1}- \cos \left(\frac{(2m+3)\pi-y}{n+1}\right)}  - \frac{1}{\cos \frac{\pi}{n+1}- \cos \left(\frac{(2m+3)\pi+y}{n+1}\right)} \right] $$

Notice that $G(0) = 0$ and $G'(y) > 0$ for $0 < y < \pi$, so $G(\pi) > 0$ which implies

$$S_n\left(\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi \right) - S_n\left(\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi \right)>  S_n\left(\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi \right) - S_n\left(\frac{2m+5}{n+1}\pi \right)$$

When $m = \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor -1 $ we have $\frac{2m+3}{n+1} < \pi < \frac{2m+5}{n+1} = \pi + \delta$. Hence,

$$S_n\left(\frac{2m+5}{n+1}\pi \right) = S_n(\pi + \delta) = S_n(\pi + \delta - 2\pi) = S_n(\delta - \pi)= - S_n(\pi - \delta) < 0,$$

Since $\frac{2m+3}{n+1}$ is the last relative extremum point before $\pi$, $S_n(\pi) = 0$, and $\frac{2m+3}{n+1} < \pi - \delta < \pi$,  it follows that

$$S_n\left(\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi \right) > 0 >  S_n\left(\frac{2m+5}{n+1}\pi \right)$$

Thus, for all $m = 0,1,\ldots, \lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor -1$ we have

$$S_n\left(\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi \right) - S_n\left(\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi \right) > 0$$

Comment: Why is $G'(y) > 0$?

Comment: @Peanut: For $0 < y < \pi$ we see immediately that $\sin \frac{\pi}{n+1}\sin y > 0$.  Now $\frac{\pi}{n+1} < \frac{(2m+3)\pi - y}{n+1} < \frac{(2m+3) \pi + y}{n+1} < \pi$, and the cosine function is decreasing on the interval $[0,\pi]$. So $0 < \cos \frac{\pi}{n+1}- \cos \left(\frac{(2m+3)\pi-y}{n+1}\right) < \cos \frac{\pi}{n+1}- \cos \left(\frac{(2m+3)\pi+y}{n+1}\right)$ and the term inside $[\ldots]$ must be positive.

Comment: For this reason I went through a series of steps using trigonometric identities to get the expression  $\cos \frac{\pi}{n+1} - \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n+1} +x \right)$ in the denominator of (1).

Comment: Thank you! Now I got you! And for the last statement where you say "it can be shown that...", do you think I can prove it myself or is it involved? XD

Comment: This  along with the original post is a great series of questions. When I said before that this monotonicity of the maxima was "clear" I meant that I could see from numerical evidence that it was likely and then tried to justify -- which turned out for me to be not so easy. Again to show these differences are all positive follows from another observation so it should be possible to fill in the final gap.  I'll work on it some more.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that very much! Hopefully waiting for the final step!

Comment: @Peanut: I made some updates.

Comment: One last question: everything is clear also from the graph. But why is it $S_n(\pi-\delta) > 0$? Also notice that I think an equality sign should be introduced, since for example when $n=4$, $m$ is at most $0$ and therefore $S_n(\frac{2m+5}{n+1}\pi) = 0$. Apart from this sign, I fail to see why it should be $\ge 0$, though it's super obvious from the graph. Am I missing something?

Comment: There has to be a last maximum point before $\pi$.  I called it $\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi$ above by shifting the index, but to be more clear it is the last point of the form $\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi$ where $m =0,1,\ldots, M$ -- so $x_M =\frac{2M+1}{n+1}\pi < \pi$.  SInce $S_n(\pi) =0$ and there are no relative minima between $x_M$ and $\pi$, if $\pi - \delta$ is between these points we must have $S_n(\pi - x_0) > 0$. If it happened to be $0$ then we would have $\pi - \delta = \pi$ which is not the case.  Now what do you think the value of $M$ is?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, $M= \frac{n-1}{2}$ and $\frac{2M+1}{n+1}\pi = \frac{n}{n+1}\pi < \pi$. Also $\frac{2(M+1)+1}{n+1}\pi = \frac{2M+1}{n+1}\pi + \frac{2}{n+1}\pi = \frac{n}{n+1}\pi + \frac{2}{n+1}\pi =\frac{n+2}{n+1}\pi > \pi$, so indeed the index $M$ corresponds to the last maximum before $\pi$.  Now work this out for $n$ even.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's more clear!

Comment: Also if $n$ is even, then the next point beyond the last maximum is $x_{M+1}= \pi$ as you saw but then $S_n(x_{M+1}) = 0$ and we still prove the differences are greater than $0$.

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 3):

**Remark**: One year ago, I analyzed the monotonicity of the function values at all local minimizers,
when I tried to answer [Inequality $\sum\limits_{1\le k\le n}\frac{\sin kx}{k}\ge 0$ (Fejer-Jackson)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376273/inequality-sum-limits-1-le-k-le-n-frac-sin-kxk-ge-0-fejer-jackson/3279332#3279332).
Here, I give the analysis of the monotonicity of the function values at all local maximizers.

**Problem**: Given positive integer $n\ge 3$, all the local maximizer of $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin kx}{k}$ on $(0, \pi)$ are given by $x_m = \frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi, m=0, 1, \cdots, \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$.
Prove that $f(x_m) > f(x_{m+1})$ for all $m=0, 1, \cdots, \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor - 1$.

**Proof**: Since $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t) \mathrm{d} t + f(0)$, we have
\begin{align}
f(x_{m+1}) - f(x_m) &= \int_{\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi}^{\frac{2m+3}{n+1}\pi} f'(t) \mathrm{d} t
= \int_{\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi}^{\frac{2m+2}{n+1}\pi} \Big( f'(t) + f'(t + \tfrac{\pi}{n+1})\Big) \mathrm{d} t. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Since $f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \cos kx = \frac{\sin \frac{nx}{2} \cos \frac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}$, we have,
for all $t\in [\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi, \frac{2m+2}{n+1}\pi]$,
\begin{align*}
&f'(t) + f'(t + \tfrac{\pi}{n+1})\\
=\ & \frac{\sin \frac{nt}{2} \cos \frac{(n+1)t}{2}}{\sin \frac{t}{2}} + \frac{\sin (\frac{nt}{2} + \frac{n}{2n+2}\pi)
\cos (\frac{(n+1)t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2})}{\sin (\frac{t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2n+2})}\\
=\ & - \frac{\sin (\frac{nt}{2} - m\pi)\sin (\frac{(n+1)t}{2} - \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2})}{\sin \frac{t}{2}} \\
& - \frac{\sin (\frac{nt}{2} + \frac{n}{2n+2}\pi - m\pi)\sin (\frac{(n+1)t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2})}{\sin (\frac{t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2n+2})} \tag{2}\\
=\ & - \frac{\sin (\frac{nt}{2} - m\pi)\sin (\frac{(n+1)t}{2} - \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2})}{\sin \frac{t}{2}} \\
& - \frac{\cos (\frac{nt}{2} + \frac{n}{2n+2}\pi - m\pi - \frac{\pi}{2})\cos (\frac{(n+1)t}{2} - \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2})}{\sin (\frac{t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2n+2})}\\
\le\ & - \frac{\sin (\frac{nt}{2} - m\pi)\sin (\frac{(n+1)t}{2} - \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2})}{\sin (\frac{t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2n+2})} \\
& - \frac{\cos (\frac{nt}{2} - m\pi )\cos (\frac{(n+1)t}{2} - \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2})}{\sin (\frac{t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2n+2})}  \tag{3}\\
\le\ & - \frac{\cos \frac{\pi - t}{2}}{\sin (\frac{t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2n+2})} \\
\le\ & 0
\end{align*}
where in (2) we have used
$\sin(\alpha - m\pi) \sin (\beta - \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2}) = -\sin \alpha \cos \beta$,
and in (3) we have used
\begin{align}
&0 < \frac{nt}{2} + \frac{n}{2n+2}\pi - m\pi - \frac{\pi}{2} < \frac{nt}{2} - m\pi < \pi, \\
&0 \le \frac{(n+1)t}{2} - \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2} \le \frac{\pi}{2},\\
&0 < \frac{t}{2} < \frac{t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2n+2} < \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}
Also, note that $f'(\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi) + f'(\frac{2m+1}{n+1}\pi + \tfrac{\pi}{n+1}) = -1 < 0$.
From (1), we have $f(x_{m+1}) < f(x_m)$. We are done.

Comment: Wow this is a cool answer! I think it's even simpler!